# Generated test classes use JUnit 4

Tags: java, junit, openapi-generator

When using the [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate [Java client code](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java) via the [Maven Plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin) then there are *JUnit* tests generated as well. This makes sense, in particular for keeping the coverage restriction (code must be covered by tests for x percent) in your project.

The issue is that theses generated JUnit tests are designed by default to utilize *JUnit 4* but we are using *JUnit 5*.

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

How can we configure the [Java Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java) in such a way that the generated tests using *JUnit 5* instead?

Comment: This question is much better that I originally thought :) To be honest, I just suspect that you didn't read the documentation properly, and I was curious to verify it. It seems like there is absolutely no mention of the JUnit jupiter version 5 support for the "java" generator, which is a shame. It seems like it is not supported at all :( but I have not found a clear proof of it so I put this as a comment only.

Comment: I would also say that this is currently not supported. So feel free to raise a feature request on their GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks and I did the GitHub feature request: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16352